# How to catch the "Call to undefined method" error in PHP 7?

Tags: php, error-handling, exception, try-catch, php-7

I use my own simple error handling and can actually catch&log everything I need. But now I need to catch an error with `try{}catch(){}`. The error, that I expect occurring sometimes at that place, is the "Call to undefined method" error. I can catch it like this:

```
try {
    $someObject->someMethodTheObjectDoesntProvide();
} catch (Error $e) {
    // do something else
}
```

But the `Error` class in the `catch` clause is a bit to generic. I'd like to catch only this type of error.

**Is there a way to restrict the catching to a particular "type" of errors?**

<sub>Without using `strpos($errorMessage)`... ;)</sub>

Comment: Nope, only different error/exception classes; and this is just a generic `Error` class

Comment: I'm not sure if `__call()` will intercept calls to non-existent methods (or only to non-accessible methods), and allow you to throw a custom exception that could then be caught and handed differently to other errors

Comment: You probably want to catch any error that happens, not just a specific one. But you could take a specific action within your `catch` block based on the type of error thrown

Comment: Using a magic __call() method in your classes can be used to throw custom exceptions if a method doesn't exist - [Demo](https://3v4l.org/4YGb0)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using a magic `__call()` method in your classes can be used to throw custom exceptions if a method doesn't exist

```
class myCustomException extends Exception {
}

class someClass {
    public function __call($name, $arguments) {
        if (!method_exists($this, $name)) {
            throw new myCustomException($name . ' has shuffled the mortal coil');
        }
    }
}


$someObject = new someClass();
try {
    $someObject->someMethodTheObjectDoesntProvide();
} catch (myCustomException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/4YGb0)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer and demo! Unfortunately it doesn't solve the problem, since it has a very inconvenient limitation: Using this approach assumes, that the class `SomeClass` of the method `someMethodTheObjectDoesntProvide()` has to implement something like a `HasCallMagicMethod` interface. It's normal for non-built-in exceptions&errors, but `Notice` is a built-in one and should be caught without implementing anything special in the "throwing" class. However, the problem cannot be solved another way (yet) and your suggestion is a very good workaround. Thanks for it once again!

Answer (score 1):

I know I'm over 18 months too late but have you considered doing what [@Mark Baker](/users/324584/mark-baker) suggested but instead throw a [`BadMethodCallException`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.badmethodcallexception.php)?